# processing data frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have this data frame. I would like to put each unique Dept and place the corresponding Name under each unique Dept. As you can see there are multiple Dept. For example, final dcoument should look like this:

```
Internet
    Public-Web
    Intranet
BackOffice
    Batch
    BackEnd
BackEnd
   WebLogic
   Oracle
```

dput(x)

```
structure(list(ID = c(1234L, 2345L, 6789L, 3456L, 7890L, 1987L
), Name = structure(c(5L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 6L, 4L), .Label = c("BackEnd", 
"Batch", "Intranet", "Oracle", "Public-Web", "WebLogic"), class = "factor"), 
    Dept = structure(c(3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("BackEnd", 
    "BackOffice", "Internet"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("ID", 
"Name", "Dept"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Any ideas how I would do this in R?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll assume you may have duplicates, and therefore use `unique`:

```
for(dept in unique(x$Dept)){
  print(dept)
  x2 <- subset(x,subset=Dept==dept)
  for(name in unique(x2$Name)){
    print(paste(sep="","  ",name))
  }
}
```

Replace the `print` whith whatever you need.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `split` to achieve this:

```
split(as.character(df$Name), df$Dept)

# $BackEnd
# [1] "WebLogic" "Oracle"  
# 
# $BackOffice
# [1] "Batch"   "BackEnd"
# 
# $Internet
# [1] "Public-Web" "Intranet"
```

If you want unique entries, then just do:

```
df <- unique(df[, 2:3])
split(as.character(df$Name), df$Dept)
```

Comment: I need to use a two for loops. For each unique Dept, I need to list out the Name. I will be doing more processing under Name in the second loop.

Comment: I don't understand your comment. Arun answer is much faster than the two loops.

Comment: I guess he just doesn't know how to iterate after the `split`

Comment: you mean he's not interested in "storing" this in a variable, rather just printing?

Comment: something like that, yes. My guess, anyway